# TypeORM bulk insert?

Tags: express, mariadb, backend, bulkinsert, typeorm

How do i bulk insert multiple records in 1 query so my db will be efficient
I want to create Office and insert multiple new equipments into that office.
Table/model code:

OFFICE

```
@Entity({ name: 'offices' })
export class Office extends Timestamps {

    @OneToMany(() => Equipment, (equipment: Equipment) => equipment.office, {
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
    })
    equipment: Array<Equipment>;
}
```

EQUIPMENT

```
@Entity({ name: 'equipment' })
export class Equipment extends Timestamps {
    @Column({
        name: 'equipment_id',
        type: 'int',
        nullable: false,
        width: 2,
        default: 0
    })
    equipment_id: number;

    @ManyToOne(() => Office, (office: Office) => office.equipment)
    @JoinColumn({ name: 'office_id' })
    office: Office;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to use [cascades](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/relations.md#cascades) property in relationships:

```
@Entity({ name: 'offices' })
export class Office extends Timestamps {

    @OneToMany(() => Equipment, (equipment: Equipment) => equipment.office, {
        cascade: true, // <= here
        onDelete: 'CASCADE',
        onUpdate: 'CASCADE'
    })
    equipment: Array<Equipment>;
}
```

Now if you set equipment when creating an instance of Office, it automatically insert an Equipment instance into database:

```
await Office.create({equipment: ['whatever']}).save();
```

Or if you use data mapper approach with repositories based on this [link](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/active-record-data-mapper):

```
const officeRepository = connection.getRepository(Office);
const office = new Office();
const equipment1 = new Equipment(); // and set your properties or make more instances

office.equipment = [equipment1]; // or more instances
await officeRepository.save(office);
```

Comment: Did not know that i have to use cascade:true . .. cool. 
But how can i use await Office.create({equipment: ['whatever']}).save(); with Repositories ? Because I use TypeORM repository to handle my db stuff.

Comment: Based on this link [https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/active-record-data-mapper], it's pretty easy to do that. I edit my answer.

Comment: @PuriaRadJahanbani What If we don't know how many `equipment` models needs to be saved into `office` model ? Is there any way to map through them and insert all of them into office ?

Comment: @MehdiFaraji In that case, I suggest using a loop method for creating the instances. Then, you can add them to the array like `office.equipment = [...equipments]`